# More concise / efficient XSLT

Tags: xslt

How can the XSLT transformation below be more concise?  It works, but I still haven't been able to see the problem declaratively (being a relative XSLT novice), and feel this solution is a procedural & rather verbose solution.  I would like to see how someone with an intuitive feel for the declarative approach would solve / simplify it?

The XSLT is used to construct a vertical navigation element that has three levels of depth.  The navigation element expands/collapses depending on which node is selected.  Css classes (active) are also applied depending on which level is selected.

It takes 2 parameters, id and query_string.

There is a special case node 'News' in the XML this acts upon - all descendent nodes from this node have the same id, so query_string is used to differentiate between them.

Here is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="id" select="'id:144016'"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="query_string" select="'year=2012&amp;month=12'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="//siteMapNode[@id=$id and @query_string=$query_string]"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//siteMapNode[@id=$id and @query_string=$query_string]/ancestor-or-self::*[@depth=1]" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="//siteMapNode[@id=$id]/ancestor::*[@depth=1]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//siteMapNode[@id=$id]/ancestor-or-self::*[@depth=1]" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//siteMapNode[@id=$id]" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="siteMapNode/siteMapNode/siteMapNode">
<xsl:variable name="matchidandyearpartofquery" select="count(self::node()[@id=$id and @query_string=substring($query_string, 1, 9)])" />
<xsl:variable name="matchid" select="count(self::node()[@id=$id])" />    
<xsl:variable name="matchdescendentid" select="count(self::node()//*[@id=$id and @query_string=substring($query_string, 1, 9)])" />
<li>
  <xsl:if test="$matchidandyearpartofquery &gt; 0 or $matchdescendentid &gt; 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>active</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
  </a>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="self::node()[@id=$id and @query_string=substring($query_string, 1, 9)]">
    <xsl:if test="./*">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::node()//*[@id=$id and @query_string=substring($query_string, 1, 9)]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::node()[@id=$id]">
    <xsl:if test="./*">
      <xsl:if test="./*[not(@id=$id)]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::node()//*[@id=$id]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>      
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="siteMapNode/siteMapNode/siteMapNode/siteMapNode">
<xsl:variable name="matchidandyearpartofquery" select="count(self::node()[@id=$id and @query_string=$query_string])" />
<xsl:variable name="matchid" select="count(self::node()[@id=$id])" />
<xsl:variable name="matchdescendentid" select="count(self::node()//*[@id=$id and @query_string=substring($query_string, 1, 9)])" />
<li>
  <xsl:if test="$matchidandyearpartofquery &gt; 0 or $matchdescendentid &gt; 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>active icon-nav-left</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
  </a>
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="self::node()[@id=$id and @query_string=$query_string]">
    <xsl:if test="./*">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::node()//*[@id=$id and @query_string=substring($query_string, 1, 9)]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::node()[@id=$id]">
    <xsl:if test="./*">
      <xsl:if test="./*[not(@id=$id)]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
          <xsl:sort select="@month" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>    
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</li>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="siteMapNode/siteMapNode/siteMapNode/siteMapNode/siteMapNode">
<xsl:variable name="matchidandyearpartofquery" select="count(self::node()[@id=$id and @query_string=$query_string])" />
<li>
  <xsl:if test="$matchidandyearpartofquery &gt; 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>active icon-nav-left</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
  </a>
</li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And some example XML input

```
<siteMapNode id="id:144037" title="Home" url="index.jsp" depth="0" show_in_top="Yes" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="">
  <siteMapNode id="id:144037" title="Home" url="index.jsp" depth="1" show_in_top="Yes" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
  <siteMapNode id="id:144513" title="Company" url="our-company/index.jsp" depth="1" show_in_top="Yes" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="">
    <siteMapNode id="id:144615" title="At a glance" url="our-company/at-a-glance.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
    <siteMapNode id="id:144005" title="Our Brands" url="our-company/our-brands.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
    <siteMapNode id="id:144629" title="Our Products" url="our-company/our-products.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
    <siteMapNode id="id:144638" title="Our Global Purpose" url="our-company/our-global-purpose.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
    <siteMapNode id="id:144002" title="Company History" url="our-company/company-history.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
    <siteMapNode id="id:144003" title="Leadership" url="our-company/leadership.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="" />
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode id="id:144016" title="News" url="news-press/newslisting.jsp" depth="1" show_in_top="Yes" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="" month="" year="">
    <siteMapNode id="id:144016" title="2012 Archive" url="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="year=2012" month="" year="2012">
      <siteMapNode id="id:144016" title="December" url="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012&amp;month=12" depth="3" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="year=2012&amp;month=12" month="12" year="2012" />
      <siteMapNode id="id:144016" title="April" url="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012&amp;month=4" depth="3" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="year=2012&amp;month=4" month="4" year="2012" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode id="id:144016" title="2013 Archive" url="news-press/newslisting.jsp" depth="2" show_in_top="No" show_in_footer="No" use_as_default="No" query_string="year=2013" month="" year=""/>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

And here is an example of the expected output HTML (here, the month december in the year 2012 has been selected from the news section)

```
<li class="active"><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012">2012 Archive</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="active icon-nav-left"><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012&amp;month=12">December</a></li>
    <li><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012&amp;month=4">April</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp">2013 Archive</a></li>
```

Comment: If you could provide an example of your input XML, that would help.

Comment: ... and the expected output as well.

Comment: i've added examples of both - any better?

Comment: XSLT is designed to be used as a declarative language. Usually, a good way to refactor stylesheets is by replacing conditions (`if` and `choose`) and `for-each` loops (but you already don't have any) with xpath conditions in `apply-templates` or `template`.

Comment: Better, but: (1) your input XML is invalid as not every `siteMapNode` has a closing element, (2) your XSLT stylesheet is not valid as it is missing the opening `xsl:stylesheet` element and the `xsl:variable` elements and (3) the expected output HTML is confusing because it has a text element `2013 Archive` which does not appear in the input XML at all. Please post *valid* XML input, the  *complete* XSLT stylesheet and the *exact* output you obtain from it.

Comment: Have made the amends suggested.

Comment: note on amends:  stylesheet is now valid, xml & output are now accurate

Comment: @BenL any further opinion?

Comment: I'm still not sure your XSLT stylesheet will work as the `id` parameter is not declared. (Should this be `tcmid` instead?)  I got it to work after fixing that (though with "ambiguous rule match" errors for your templates). I've now posted my solution - please give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, with hopefully helpful comments. It works with your example but you may have more specific requirements this doesn't take into account. Still, I hope it will be useful to you.

The following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:param name="id" select="'id:144016'"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="query_string" select="'year=2012&amp;month=12'"/>

  <!-- Match the siteMapNode element at depth 1 with the specified id. Just apply 
       templates to its children. -->
  <xsl:template match="siteMapNode[@id=$id and @depth='1']"
        priority="5">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the siteMapNode element with the specified id that partially match the 
       query string. These will have child elements so apply templates and keep
       going. -->
  <xsl:template match="siteMapNode[@id=$id and contains($query_string, @query_string)]"
        priority="1">
    <li class="active">
      <xsl:call-template name="anchor"/>
      <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the siteMapNode element with the specified id that completely match the 
       query string. -->
  <xsl:template match="siteMapNode[@id=$id and $query_string=@query_string]"
        priority="10">
    <li class="active icon-nav-left">
      <xsl:call-template name="anchor"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the remaining siteMapNode elements with the specified id.
       This template has the default priority of 0.5. -->
  <xsl:template match="siteMapNode[@id=$id]">
    <li>
      <xsl:call-template name="anchor"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- The anchor element we output is common, so put it into a template we can call. -->
  <xsl:template name="anchor">
      <a href="{@url}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
      </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- The built-in template for elements and the root node is already doing what we want, 
       so we don't need to include it explicitly. It's below, commented out, for 
       reference. -->
<!--  <xsl:template match="*|/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>-->

  <!-- Don't want to output text or attribute nodes unless we explicitly say so, so we 
       need to override the built-in templates for these. -->
  <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives the following output when applied to your example input XML:

```
<li class="active"><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012">2012 Archive</a><ul>
      <li class="active icon-nav-left"><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012&amp;month=12">December</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp?year=2012&amp;month=4">April</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="news-press/newslisting.jsp">2013 Archive</a></li>
```

Comment: The transformation fails for me when I try this - says 'variables cannot be used within an expression'... I thoguht you couldn't use variables within a template match???

Comment: Sorry, you are right (though this worked for me using Saxon HE 9.0.4.4N - I'll have to look more into why). I will look at it again soon and (hopefully) get it working.